# How to install GWT in netbeans and or smartGWT and add Click Handler in code

Tags: java, gwt, netbeans

Sorry I'm very new to question asking if you need more information please let me know. I really need this please reply if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this https://netbeans.org/kb/74/web/quickstart-webapps-gwt.html

and also this http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiHandlers.html

That should take care of you.

Comment: Thank you so much I really needed it.

Comment: Those links lead to pages which are no longer up to date, we couldn't do this anymore.